# Change font color on mouseover

Tags: javascript, html, css, dynamic-html

I'm trying to change the color, when I mouseover `elem1`, but my code doesn't work..

```js
let user1 = new user('Stan');
window.onload = function() {
  let elem1 = document.getElementById('u1');
  let getNum = document.getElementById("u1").value = "14";
  elem1.addEventListener("mouseover", highlight);

  function highlight() {
    document.getElementsById("u1").value = "14".style.color = "#00ff00";
    //alert(getNum); getNum check
  }

  function user(name) {
    this.name = name;
  }
};
```

```css
.calCell {
  background-color: rgba(255, 228, 196, 0.1);
  font-family: JMH Arkham;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: khaki;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-color: rgba(176, 196, 222, 0.2);
}
```

```html
<p id="u1">
  <script>
    (document.write(user1.name[0]);
  </script>
</p>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="calCell">01</button></td>
    <td><button class="calCell">14</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

I will be happy if someone can help me to resolve this!

Comment: `document.getElementsById("u1").value` There is nothing called getElement**s**ById

Comment: use css `:hover` selector rather than js (if you only want to change colour on hover)

Comment: @Pete seems he needs this hover only when a button element has a specific value.

Comment: Thanks Krishna, I fixed this. However this fix doesn't resolve the problem

Comment: What are you trying to do? Just a hover question tends to have css solution. Maybe explain the interaction of the user and the expected result.

Comment: I need highlight specific values, when mouseover on elem1

Comment: @Pete what it would be the css selector for that?

Comment: @August see my edit with value

Comment: @Stanislav post a fiddle link

Comment: That selector doesn't seem to work: https://jsfiddle.net/zhsn3tfu/

Comment: see working:https://jsfiddle.net/zhsn3tfu/2/

Comment: and see also my answer there is explain there

Comment: Guys there is a link https://jsfiddle.net/gmvxc7tw/3/

Comment: I want do event (mouseover) on elem1 (it's a paragraph), event do highlight function (it must be :hover on specified td when mouse on elem1)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use JQuery for resolve this.
@Abhishek Mishra Thanks for idea!

```js
//JQuery starts from here
$('#u1').mouseover(function(){
 $('.calCell:contains(11)').css('color', 'goldenrod');
});
$('#u1').mouseout(function(){
 $('.calCell').css('color', 'khaki');
});
//JQuery over here
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply do it in css: `.calCell:hover`

Learn about `:hover`:https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp

```css
.calCell {
 background-color: rgba(255,228,196,0.1);
 font-family: JMH Arkham;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: khaki;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 border-color: rgba(176,196,222,0.2);
}
.calCell:hover{
color:red;
}
```

```html
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><button class="calCell">01</button></td>
   <td><button class="calCell">14</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

**Accordding Value:**

`.calCell[value="14"]:hover` and add to button `<button class="calCell" value="01">01</button>`

```css
  .calCell {
     background-color: rgba(255,228,196,0.1);
     font-family: JMH Arkham;
     font-size: 50px;
     color: khaki;
     text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
     width: 70px;
     height: 70px;
     border-color: rgba(176,196,222,0.2);
    }
    .calCell[value="14"]:hover{
    color:red;
    }
```

```html
<tbody>
      <tr>
       <td><button class="calCell" value="01">01</button></td>
       <td><button class="calCell"  value="14">14</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

CSS hover with transition

```css
.calCell {
  background-color: rgba(255, 228, 196, 0.1);
  font-family: JMH Arkham;
  font-size: 50px;
  color: khaki;
  text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  border-color: rgba(176, 196, 222, 0.2);
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.calCell:hover {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<p id="u1">
</p>
<tbody>
  <tr>
    <td><button class="calCell">01</button></td>
    <td><button class="calCell">14</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('button.calCell').hover(function() {
   $(this).css('color','red')
});
$('button.calCell').mouseleave(function() {
   $(this).css('color','khaki')
});
```

```css
.calCell {
 background-color: rgba(255,228,196,0.1);
 font-family: JMH Arkham;
 font-size: 50px;
 color: khaki;
 text-shadow: -1px 0 black, 0 2px black, 2px 0 black, 0 -1px black;
 width: 70px;
 height: 70px;
 border-color: rgba(176,196,222,0.2);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p id="u1"></script></p>
<tbody>
  <tr>
   <td><button class="calCell">01</button></td>
   <td><button class="calCell">14</button></td>
  </tr>
</tbody>
```